# Navigation Drawer, ListView Items don't show

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I'm trying do a news sports app with a `NavigationDrawer`. But when I open the app I want to show a `WebView` and after from left to come the `ListView`.  I did something but now the `ListView` doesn't show the items. I have 4 classes and 2 xml.

```
package com.baronescu.sportsnews2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       String[] menu;
       DrawerLayout dLayout;
       ListView dList;
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        menu = new String[]{"Football","Tennis","Basketball","Hockey","Handball"};
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
        dList.setAdapter(adapter);
        dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
        dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
        dLayout.closeDrawers();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
        Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
        detail.setArguments(args);
          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.dfurl, detail).commit();
      }
        });


        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run (){
                try {
                    sleep(2000);                        
                } catch (InterruptedException e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent odu = new Intent ("com.baronescu.sportsnews2.DEFAULTURL");
                    startActivity(odu);

                }   
            }
        };
        timer.start();  




  }

  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}



package com.baronescu.sportsnews2;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView text;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_detail_fragment, container, false);
        String menu = getArguments().getString("Menu");
        text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        text.setText(menu);
        return view;
    }
}


package com.baronescu.sportsnews2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import com.baronescu.sportsnews2.OurViewClient;



public class DefaultUrl extends Activity {

    WebView firstnews;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstnews = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.dfurl);
        firstnews.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());

        firstnews.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        firstnews.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        firstnews.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        try {
            firstnews.loadUrl("http://www.digisport.ro");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


package com.baronescu.sportsnews2;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class OurViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        v.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}






<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sportsnews" >

    <!-- android:id="@+id/content_frame" -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
    <!-- android:layout_height="match_parent" > -->

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/dfurl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="40px" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.baronescu.sportsnews2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DefaultUrl"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.baronescu.sportsnews2.DEFAULTURL" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Start reading that does not hurt!**

**[implementing drawer navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout)**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> - The ***main content view*** (the FrameLayout above) must be the first child in the DrawerLayout because the XML order implies
>     z-ordering and the drawer must be on top of the content.
> - The main content view is set to match the parent view's width and height, because it represents the entire UI when the navigation drawer is hidden.
> - The drawer view (the ListView) must specify its horizontal gravity with the android:layout_gravity attribute. To support right-to-left (RTL) languages, specify the value with "start" instead of "left" (so the drawer appears on the right when the layout is RTL).
> - The drawer view specifies ts width in dp units and the height matches the parent view. The drawer width should be no more than 320dp so the user can   always see a portion of the main content.

As a good practice i recommend:

1. **create layout for drawer as above**
2. **create main activity consuming layout**
3. **create second layout (main content layout) with WebView**
4. **make fragment for coresponding layout**
5. **add fragment via transaction in main activity**